# @my_bot.message_handler(content_types="text") AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

if you're facing this problem while you try to create your Telegram Bots.
problem:

> @my_bot.message_handler(content_types="text")
>
> AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'

Try this solution:

```
1- open the terminal on your text editor.
2- past this command : 
pip3 uninstall telebot
pip3 uninstall PyTelegramBotAPI
pip3 install pyTelegramBotAPI
pip3 install --upgrade pyTelegramBotAPI
```

Comment: Not a question, and updating your library to fit the API version you're using is not very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

1. open the terminal on your text editor.
2. past this command

:

```
pip3 uninstall telebot
pip3 uninstall PyTelegramBotAPI 
pip3 install pyTelegramBotAPI 
pip3 install --upgrade pyTelegramBotAPI
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).